# Laravel Passport Set Session

Tags: laravel, laravel-passport

Getting below error when I am trying to set session by laravel passport

"message": "Session store not set on request.",
"exception": "RuntimeException",

Comment: Do you have `\Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class` in Kernel.php web section?

Comment: But I am using passport api section. Then how I can set it?

Answer (score 7):

This can be done in several ways.

### 1. Add `StartSession` middleware after `auth:api`.

This is the most straightforward solution. Add the following three lines right after `auth:api`.

```
EncryptCookies::class,
AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
StartSession::class,
```

Then remove `\Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class` from
`middlewarePriority` protected property. Without this `StartSession` middleware will get control **before** `auth` and, more importantly, before `EncryptCookies` middlewares which, basically, will always lead to a new session.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http;

class Kernel extends HttpKernel
{
    // Copy this values from
    // \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel::$middlewarePriority
    // then remove or comment line with StartSession. Without it,
    // StartSession middleware will get control right before Auth.
    // Which, basically, will create a new session because at this
    // time cookies are still encrypted.
    protected $middlewarePriority = [
        // \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
        \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
        \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
    ];

    /**
     * The application's route middleware groups.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'web' => [
            ...
        ],
        'api' => [
            'throttle:120,1',
            'bindings',
            'auth:api', // https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/passport#protecting-routes

            // Add the following three middleware right after `auth`
            // in order to have a session.
            EncryptCookies::class,
            AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
            StartSession::class,
        ],
    ];
}
```

### 2. Create your own `StartSession` middleware.

Having your own middleware for starting session will free you from necessaty to override `middlewarePriority`.

First, create a new class.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Foundation\Application;
use Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession;
use Illuminate\Session\SessionManager;

class StartSessionShared extends StartSession
{
    public function __construct(Application $app, SessionManager $manager)
    {
        parent::__construct($manager);
        $app->singleton(StartSessionShared::class);
    }
}
```

Then add the following three lines right after `auth:api`.

```
EncryptCookies::class,
AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
StartSessionShared::class,
```

One important note in this method is call to `$app->singleton`. Without it Laravel will always create a new instance of this class. Which will lead `\Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::terminate` method to skip saving session.

### 3. Create your own `StartSessionReadonly` middleware.

This is a good choice if you want just to share session from `web`
guard to `api` guard and don't intend to alter its values in any way. This was my case.

Create the following `StartSessionReadonly` middleware. Then use it in `api` guard instead of `StartSession` and two its friends.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Encryption\DecryptException;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Encryption\Encrypter;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Session\Session;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession;
use Illuminate\Session\SessionManager;

/**
 * Middleware for sharing session between `web` and `api` guards.
 * Since the latter is essentially stateless, the session from
 * `web` is shared as readonly.
 *
 * @package App\Http\Middleware
 */
class StartSessionReadonly extends StartSession
{
    protected $encrypter;

    public function __construct(Encrypter $encrypter, SessionManager $manager)
    {
        parent::__construct($manager);
        $this->encrypter = $encrypter;
    }

    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        // If a session driver has been configured, we will need to start the session here
        // so that the data is ready for an application. Note that the Laravel sessions
        // do not make use of PHP "native" sessions in any way since they are crappy.
        if ($this->sessionConfigured()) {
            $request->setLaravelSession($this->startSession($request));
        }

        return $next($request);
    }

    public function getSession(Request $request)
    {
        return tap($this->manager->driver(), function (Session $session) use ($request) {
            $payload = $request->cookies->get($session->getName());
            $unserialize = EncryptCookies::serialized($session->getName());
            try {
                $session->setId($this->encrypter->decrypt($payload, $unserialize));
            }
            catch (DecryptException $exception) {
            }
        });
    }
}
```

After updating `app/Http/Kernel.php` you will have readonly session for all of your api.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http;

class Kernel extends HttpKernel
{
    [...]

    /****
     * The application's route middleware groups.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $middlewareGroups = [
        [...]
        'api' => [
            'throttle:120,1',
            'bindings',
            'auth:api', // https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/passport#protecting-routes
            StartSessionReadonly::class,
        ],
    ];
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer and detailed post, but I am confused. Isn't the whole point of passport to be stateless thus session-less?

Comment: You're right, oauth is stateless. This is why I emphasize it by naming middleware `StartSessionReadonly`. The only reason it is here is to allow frontend access to the same set of api. This is kind of a hack.

Comment: Thanks, but I still don't understand. Why do we need to include session in the API? Why doesn't passport allow us to make requests?

Comment: Think of it as _`oauth_token` which stored in session_. When you use OAuth you have to send `oauth_token` with each request (so that `Auth::user()` will return user associated with this `oauth token`). In this case frontend have no `oauth_token` to send. But it sends session id with each request. `StartSessionReadonly` restores this session so that `Auth::user()` will return currently logged in user. It's not a session in a usual sense. Just a way to pass currently logged in user to the API.

Comment: The 3rd solution is not working in Laravel 8 anymore, because the `startSession` method requires a Session object to be passed in. So I think you have to do `$session = $this->getSession();` first and pass that in. I wasn't quite able to get it working but didn't spend too much time on it yet, for now just settling with option #2. Either way you are a lifesaver, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Laravel Passport is a token-based authentication package for laravel

> APIs typically use tokens to authenticate users and do not maintain
>   session state between requests. Laravel makes API authentication a
>   breeze using Laravel Passport, which provides a full OAuth2 server
>   implementation for your Laravel application in a matter of minutes.

Almost all the token-based systems including oAuth2 are by default stateless, which means there is no session attached to it,

Which means there is no session store.You can only rely on the token which is supplied on each request to validate the users identity.

That's why you are not able to set session when using laravel passport

Comment: In this case if I required any value like any details related to user frequently then how I can use it in laravel passport.

Comment: I need to use session value in both side like web application and also by rest call in my app.

Comment: From the API token supplied in the request, you can identify the logged in user, I think the `auth()->user()` will return the logged in user if we are using passport as well. from there onwards you can access any details on the user

Comment: I think if you tinker a bit, you can enable the session in passport. but that will defeat the purpose of having a rest API, The REST is stateless.